# How to change the value of spinner in toolbar according to click on Fragment Item?

Tags: android, android-fragments

If, I'm using spinner in the toolbar and I want, when I click on any fragment, the value spinner should also change?

How to change the value of spinner, from fragment click?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using adapter for your spinner use adapter.notifyDataChange(); after updating the adapter values.

Comment: If u r having any tutorial regarding that plz provide me or plz show me how to do this